# use cURL to send data to private Xively device

Tags: curl, xively

Is it possible to use cURL to send data to a private Xively device ?

If so could someone please post an example.

thank you

Comment: This is what I have tried:


curl --verbose --request PUT --data-binary @c:\logs\data.csv 
--header "X-ApiKey: XXXXXXX" --user XXX@XXX.com:password http://xively.com/feeds/123456.csv


and the response is:


HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to see from here. But the 301 suggests you might be using the HTTP link as opposed to HTTPS. Trying switching to HTTPS and removing the basic auth (--user) stuff and it should work.